# Execute sudo commands as www-data in PHP

Tags: php, bash, permissions, spleeter

I'm trying to execute bash script commands in PHP.

In the php file (commands.php) some commands doesn't work:

```
// works
echo shell_exec('whoami');
echo "<br>";

// works
echo shell_exec('ls -al');
echo "<br>";

// doesn't work
echo shell_exec('mkdir testfolder');
echo "<br>";

// doesn't work
shell_exec('sudo -S spleeter separate -p spleeter:2stems -o output audio_example.mp3');
echo "<br>";
```

This is the output:

```
www-data
total 272
drwxr-sr-x 2 root www-data   4096 Jul 12 23:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       4096 Jul 12 21:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 262867 Jul 12 21:36 audio_example.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data   1417 Jul 12 23:11 commands.php
```

The www-data user have permissions to this folder:

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 root www-data  4096 Jul 12 23:06 files
```

I have no problems to execute the commands as root user at the terminal. I guess there are some permission issues. What is the best way to execute bash commands with PHP?

(Ubuntu 18; Apache2; PHP7)

Comment: Does `www-data` have permission to use `sudo` without a password?

Comment: Giving `www-data` sudo access is really, really bad idea. If I were you I would rather focus on how can I execute `spleeter` without super user. As for `mkdir` command. PHP has build in `mkdir()` method.

Comment: @MartinDendis you are right. Is it the right way to change the permission of the `spleeter` command? I did the `mkdir` example to show what works.

Comment: @Barmar Do you mean to use `NOPASSWD` like here is mentioned: https://superuser.com/questions/1448987/allow-php-to-run-shell-script-with-sudo-permission

Comment: Yes, but you should restrict it to just the commands used by your script.

Comment: I didn't have luck with `NOPASSWD`.

I left the sudoers file untouched. I created a overwrite called "spleeter" in the folder sudoers.d:
`%www-data All=NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /var/www/html/spleetercommand.sh`

Parsing is ok:
`root@myServer:/var/www/html/files# sudo visudo -c  
/etc/sudoers: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/spleeter: parsed OK`

Here is the content of spleetercommand.sh:
`spleeter separate -p spleeter:2stems -o output audio_example.mp3`

In the terminal I executed like this without success:
`sudo -u www-data ./spleetercommand.sh`

@Barmar Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know much about configuring sudoers. [unix.se] is the place to ask for help with that.